# Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. │

Tags: flutter, dart

when I am trying to generate apk with command flutter build apk. I am getting the following error.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.

My kotlin version is 1.8.0, Flutter version is 3.7.8 and Dart version is 2.19.5

I am unable to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

> SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

From your exception, it seems like you haven't generated an upload-keystore.jks (storeFile) for your project. Follow Flutter's guidelines [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app) to find the command to generate the file.

Tip, move your generated key file to your flutterapp\android\app folder and simply reference it like so in your key.properties file.

```
storePassword=<password from previous step>
keyPassword=<password from previous step
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=upload-keystore.jks
```

And after doing so, make sure git doesn't upload your files by modifying your gitignore like so:

> /android/app/*.jks

> /android/key.properties